# Is there a way to connect to a docker container from USB connected android device with adb?

Tags: android, docker, adb

I have a running mock-server (jamesdbloom/mockserver) container in my docker, with published ports: 1080:1080. I would like to connect to this container from my android app, of course USB connected to my PC. I've googled about this, and i found that adb can help me, but i have no idea how can my app communicate with my mock-server.

I've set up my android studio terminal path, so i can use the adb commands, i see my attached device, and i see there is a socket for the adb server on port 5037.